# Flutter Firebase Realtime Database 'join'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart, nosql

How can I join data in flutter firebase realtime database. Data model on appended screen

I've  something like this.
 *(**app** is configuration argument)*
 *(**userId** is for ex. 'gg6G0c4PkbffGUyJ3lVJMSmd2Uf2')*

I want to get Objects from 'users', based on 'pendings' userId

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase(app: widget.app);

_pendingRef = database.reference().child('pendings/${userId}');


_pendingSubscription =
        _pendingRef.onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
      print('Child added: ${event.snapshot.value}');
    }, onError: (Object o) {
      final DatabaseError error = o;
      print('Error: ${error.code} ${error.message}');
    });
```

[image: firebase realtime database model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built-in to Firebase to support such joins. You'll have to write code in your application to load the necessary data, also known as a client-side join.

Something like:

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase(app: widget.app);

_pendingRef = database.reference().child('pendings/${userId}');

_pendingSubscription = _pendingRef.onChildAdded.listen((Event event) {
  print('Child added: ${event.snapshot.value}');
  database.reference().child('users/${event.snapshot.key}').once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    print('${snapshot.value}');
  })
});
}, onError: (Object o) {
  final DatabaseError error = o;
  print('Error: ${error.code} ${error.message}');
});

dbRoot.child('current_bracket').onValue.listen((event) {
```